# Cordova 3.4: How to Manually Install a Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I would like to manually install [this plugin](https://github.com/BastienL/GPSDetector) into my Android application, which is built on Cordova 3.4.  The plugin is compatible with Cordova up to v3.1.  The plugin checks to see if geolocation via GPS is enabled on a device.

I've attempted referencing the plugin in `res/xml/config.xml`, however this reference is removed each time I run cordova `build android`.  The result is that when I run the program I get a `Class not found` error.

Any thoughts on this particular scenario or just how to manually install a Cordova 3.4 plugin would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: What basically you have done is you have added the plugin in platform. When you do build, it will first check the plugins folder in your project not on the platform. 
So if you have that plugin in the plugins folder automatically it will sit in your platform's plugin folder and config.xml. 
But this is not in your case, may be you would not have added the plugin in the common plugin folder. 
Cordova build will take the common www folder and put in your platform www, then common plugin;s to platform plugin's.

Comment: I'm going to try Siddharth's suggestion, using Plugman. However it sounds like you're suggesting setting up the `directory\plugins\com.example.plugins\plugin.xml` file.  If this will make it work, then I'm happy to do it.  Is this correct?

Comment: thats the way you have to. Single code base

Comment: if not you shuouldnot use cordova/phonegap build to build. which will take resources from common directory not from specified platform

Comment: Interesting. I am currently using `cordova build android` to build the app, and plan to continue to do so.  To be clear, if I use Plugman to add the plugin, will it then get removed when I use `cordova build android`?  If so I will certainly use use your suggested method.

Comment: yes obviously. it will be removed if its not in common folder. please try some sample to understand the basic workflow

Answer (score 0):

**Add Plugin Features**

If you use a platform-specific workflow, you use a lower-level ***Plugman command-line interface***, separately for each targeted platform.

**Installing Plugman**

To install plugman, you must have *node* installed on your machine. Then you can run the following command from anywhere in your environment to install plugman globally, so that it is available from any directory: *$ npm install -g plugman*

**Adding a Plugin**

Once you have installed Plugman and have created a Cordova project, you can start adding plugins to the platform:

Check this link : [Plugman to manage Plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins)

**Edited** : [Plugman to Manage Plugins (3.4.0)](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins)

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I am currently using CLI to install plugins.  So by using Plugman for this plugin it will also work for Cordova 3.4?

Comment: Basically, CLI is used for all the platforms and Plugman is used for particular platform.Yes, it will work for 3.4.0. Chek my edited answer.Adding link for Plugman 3.4.0 version